# How can I find the angle between two vectors that can range from 0 rad to 2 rad, instead of the inside angle with the arccos function

Tags: python, numpy, math, trigonometry

I'm making a python script right now that is trying to find the length of an arc, where it given this information:

center of arc: x1, y1

start point of arc: x2, y2

end point of arc: x3, y3

direction, cw, ccw

so far I have been able to successfully calculate the radius, and I tried calculating the angle using the equation:

[image: equation for angle]

But for any arcs that have an angle greater than 1*pi or 180 degrees, it returns the incorrect (but correct) inside angle.

What is the correct equation knowing the radius and these three points that I can use to find the value of the angle of the arc from 0 rad/degrees to 360 degrees/2pi radians, going in either the clockwise or counterclockwise direction (it can be either or and I need to be able to calculate for both scenarios)

Code:

```
# code to find theta
aVector = np.array([x1 - x2, y1 - y2])
bVector = np.array([x1 - x3, y1 - y3])
aMag = np.linalg.norm(aVector)
bMag = np.linalg.norm(aVector)
theta = np.arcos(np.dot(aVector, bVector) / (aMag * bMag))
```

as you can see here, I'm using arccos which to my dismay only outputs 0-180 degrees

Solution/Working code:

```
# equation for angle using atan2
start = math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1)
end = math.atan2(y3 - y1, x3 - x1)
if gcodeAnalysis[tempLineNum][4] == "G3": # going CW
    start, end = end, start
tau = 2.0 * math.pi
theta = math.fmod(math.fmod(end - start, tau) + tau, tau)
```

Working Values:

```
X1 = 0.00048399999999998444
Y1 = 0.0002720000000007161
X2 = 0.378484
Y2 = -14.694728
X3 = 3.376
Y3 = -14.307
```

Proper result/value

```
Theta = 6.077209477545957
```

Assume this arc was done CCW

Comment: unfortunately the equation isn't fine, as arccos measures inside angle and I need total angle, but I will add my code

Comment: Which is positive, cw or ccw?

Comment: `np.linalg.norm[aVector]` is definitely a typo

Comment: Your radius computation looks nonsensical. Is it even relevant to the question?

Comment: I'll go by right hand rule (I think I am at least in saying so) and say CCW is positive

Comment: OK. I've posted an answer, but please fix your code.

Comment: Mad Physicist, the radius computation is for later in the code (which I didn't include) and that calculates the length, I'll remove it

Comment: Also np.linalg.norm(aVector) should've been the code, assuming numpy is imported as np

Comment: a proper [mcve] should include all inputs and expected outputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed, the range of [`math.acos`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.acos) is [0, pi], making it rather useless for telling you the relative directions of the vectors. To get full circular information about a pair of angles, you can use [`math.atan2`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.atan2). While regular [`math.atan`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.atan) has a range of [-pi/2, pi/2], `atan2` splits the inputs into two parts and returns an angle in the range (-pi, pi]. You can compute the angles relative to any reference, not necessarily relative to each other:

```
start = math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1)
end = math.atan2(y3 - y1, x3 - x1)
```

Now you can use some common formulae to find the difference between the angles in whatever direction you want. I've implemented some of these in a small utility library I made called haggis. The specific function you want is [`haggis.math.ang_diff_pos`](https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/dev/api.html#haggis.math.ang_diff_pos).

First, the "manual" computation:

```
if direction == 'cw':
    start, end = end, start
tau = 2.0 * math.pi
angle = math.fmod(math.fmod(end - start, tau) + tau, tau)
```

If you want to use my function, you can do

```
if direction == 'cw':
    start, end = end, start
angle = ang_diff_pos(start, end)
```

All of these operations can be easily vectorized using numpy if you find yourself dealing with many points all at once.

Comment: for something that should've returned 6.1 radians this calculation returned 3.8

Comment: Can you add that as a concrete example?

Comment: X1 = 0.00048399999999998444
Y1 = 0.0002720000000007161
X2 = 0.378484
Y2 = 3.376
X3 = -14.694728
Y3 = -14.307
Theta = 2.454330521843865

Comment: Could you please edit that into your question?

Comment: # equation for angle using atan2
                start = math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1)

                end = math.atan2(y3 - y1, x3 - x1)

                if gcodeAnalysis[tempLineNum][4] == "G3": # going CW

                    start, end = end, start

                tau = 2.0 * math.pi

                theta = math.fmod(math.fmod(end - start, tau) + tau, tau)

                dir = 'ccw'

                v1 = np.array([x2-x1,y2-y1])
                
                v2 = np.array( [x3-x1,y3-y1])

Comment: sorry I couldn't get the format right, there's not much formatting in the comments, should I upload a photo instead?

Comment: @AlexJones. Do not upload images. Edit your question please.

Comment: @AlexJones. Please read the help page [mcve]. You missed the point of including an actual numerical example I could test with, and instead included your interpretation of the stuff I wrote.

Comment: I re-edited to give numerical examples, where I listed out x1-y3, the result I got from the function, and the function itself, did I miss anything?

Comment: @AlexJones. I plotted the points you show. The two vectors are ~120deg apart, so around 2 radians. Start is nearly vertical, end is in the third quadrant: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0o3z.png

Comment: Whoops, I noticed my error, it was from an earlier parsing error I made when I had included your function. your function works perfectly, thank you so much for the help and I hope you have a great day

Comment: I added the values back into the post, did I do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cross product of the two vector to determine if the two vector need to rotate clock or counter-clock wise.

See code below:

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA


x1 = 0
y1 = 0
x2 = 2
y2 = 0
x3 = 2
y3 = -2
dir = 'ccw' # or ccw 

v1 = np.array([x2-x1,y2-y1])
v2 = np.array( [x3-x1,y3-y1])

# if the cross product is positive, then the two vector need to rotate counter clockwise
rot = np.cross(v1,v2)
vdir = 'ccw' if rot >0 else 'cw'

r = (v1[0]*v2[0]+v1[1]*v2[1])/(LA.norm(v1)*LA.norm(v2))

deg = np.arccos(r)/np.pi*180

if vdir != dir:
    deg = 360 -deg

print(deg)
```

Comment: will this let me choose if I want to measure the angle of the arc if I'm going clockwise or counterclockwise, or does it determine which way to measure, because I might be measuring anywhere from a  0.0001 degree to 359.999, etc, degree

Comment: @AlexJones Yes, the dir='ccw' gives you the measure of counterclockwise and dir='cw' gives you the measure of clockwise. The deg value would be the degree to rotate from vector 1 to vector 2.